# Add smaller objects to a force layout graph's circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

So, I have a force layout graph, with something like 30 circles in it. 
Some circles are connected to a central circle, some are not.

What I wanna do is have smaller objects floating around the main circles (maybe with a higher gravity or a smaller distance).

How do you reckon I should proceed? 
Thank you,

Comment: The next step would probably be to add those additional objects.

Comment: For sure. 
Would you use `append()` ? If yes, appending to the said circles or to the nodes?

Comment: As a start, you can just add more nodes to the original force layout.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I managed to do so. I styled a bit the grand-children. 
Now, do you think it would be possible to make sure the nodes 1, 2 and 3 on the screenshot (see bottom of this message) appear on the side opposite to the center? As if they were repelled by it.

http://imgur.com/mh5CJcJ

Comment: You can set custom repulsion/attraction forces.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to figure that custom repulsion thing out. 
Another keyword for my search? ;) Thanks Lars

Comment: If you posted some code or an example we may be able to help you.

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/basilesimon/9621602

Comment: Right, so the first thing I would try is give a different charge to the new nodes. You can do this by passing a function to `.charge()`, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#charge).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried with two different forms of the function (see lines 85-96, commented), without conclusive results. Am I on the good track, at least? https://gist.github.com/basilesimon/9621602

Comment: You need to return the charge as a number, e.g. `.charge(function() { if(a) return -100; else return -300; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, Lars helped me find a solution.

I started by customizing the `.charge()` to something more appropriate. The function is below, provided there's this `type="f"` in your code:

```
.charge(function(d) {
if (d.type === "f") { return -50;
} else { return -700;
}
})
```

Then, and just for design purposes, I changed the `.linkDistance` following the same method.

```
.linkDistance(function(d) {
if (d.type === "f") { return 5;
} else { return 30;
}
})
```

Here's the result: 
[image: Result]